# What is the "SchedulerBinding.instance?.cancelFrameCallbackWithId(_frameCallbackID);" Error?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, runtime-error

Why i am get this error,

Here the error,

`/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:167:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.

- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
  SchedulerBinding.instance?.cancelFrameCallbackWithId(_frameCallbackID);
  ^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:170:28: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
  SchedulerBinding.instance?.scheduleFrameCallback(_beginFrame) ?? -1;
  ^
  /C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flare_flutter-3.0.2/lib/flare_render_box.dart:272:26: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '?.' has type 'SchedulerBinding' which excludes null.
- 'SchedulerBinding' is from 'package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/scheduler/binding.dart').
  package:flutter/…/scheduler/binding.dart:1
  SchedulerBinding.instance?.cancelFrameCallbackWithId(_frameCallbackID);`

Comment: what flutter version do you use?
i think it caused by new changes on latest version of flutter. but some package not support for that changes.

Comment: i think its ok to ignore , wait until the package owner update to compatible for flutter 3.0
or you can downgrade your flutter to 2.1~

Comment: My flutter version is 3.0.5

Comment: many developers face same issue when they upgrade to flutter 3.0.

for temporary the community recommend to downgrade https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/103561#issuecomment-1124946639

Answer (score 0):

SchedulerBinding.instance was null-type object in previous version, so all the libraries are using null operators.

In flutter 3.0.2, they updated the SchedulerBinding.instance to NOT null type, but all libraries are still using null operators (which is unnecessary) that's why you getting these warnings

you will need to update libraries when
they move to flutter 3.0.2 and remove null operators.